# Testing equality for numbers using javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, equality

newbie with Javascript.  I have a javascript function that is checking user input.  The html document has two forms.  I call `validateForm(document.forms[0])` with the first form as an argument.  Then in my function I rename the argument to `TheForm`.  (e.g. `validateForm(theForm)`.)  The fields contain integers.  In `validateForm` I simply want to check equality for two form fields like this:

```
if(theForm.Field1.value == theForm.Field2.value)
{
    //do something
}
```

Pretty simple eh?  I have tried

```
theForm.Field[x].value.toString, theForm.Field[x].toString.Trim,       theForm.Field[x].
```

Also tried to assign vars for both fields and test.  Viewing the contents in Visual Studio I can see where the fields are exactly the same, and hence, the boolean check should fire.

Comment: Can you post your full code if there isn't to much?

Comment: Well toString is a method and you do not treat it like that. We need to see more code.

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive. Field1 and field1 are different. Please ensure that you are using the exact name as which you've defined as the 'name' of the fields